# Eigensystem with orthogonal elements in matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, assumptions

I have a matrix with 16 elements:

```
matrix = {{f1, -f2, -f2, f3 }, {f4, -f1, -f1, f2}, {f4, -f1, -f1, f2}, {f5, -f4, -f4, f1}}
```

I would like to calculate eigenvectors and eigenstates of the matrix, with additional assumption, that is elements f1, f2, f3, f4 and f5 are orthogonal. I've tried to call $Assumptions = f1*f2=f2*3 ... =0, but without luck. 
Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "elements are orthogonal"? The `$Assumptions` line contains syntax errors so we can't use it to infer unambiguously what you actually want or tried.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing OP meant `f1*f2 == f1*f3 == f1* f4 == f1*f5 == f2*f3 == f2*f4 == f2*f5 == f3*f4 == f3*f5== f4*f5 ==0`,

```
matrix = {{f1, -f2, -f2, f3}, {f4, -f1, -f1, f2}, {f4, -f1, -f1, f2}, {f5, -f4, -f4, f1}};
assumptions = Thread[(Subsets[Times[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5], {2}]) == 0];
ToRadicals @ FullSimplify[Eigensystem[matrix], Assumptions -> assumptions]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]